# Find the most general assumption on $a(x)$ such that this function is in $L^1(\Omega)$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , and let $$u, v \in L^p(\Omega) \quad \forall p \in[1,\infty)$$
Find the most general assumption on $a(x)$ such that:
$$\int_{\Omega} a(x)u^3v dx$$
is finite.

In practice I should find what is the most "general"  $L^q(\Omega)$ in which $a(x)$ belongs.
I hope it is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Since $\Omega $ is bounded, $L^p(\Omega )\subset L^r(\Omega )$ for all $p\leq r$. Since $u,v\in L^p$ for all $p$, I would say that the weaker assumption would be $a\in \bigcap_{p>1}L^p(\Omega ) $ (if it's really the question...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $$\frac{3}{p}+\frac{1}{q} +\frac{1}{r} =1$$ then $$\int_{\Omega} a(x) v(x) u^3 (x) dx \leq \left(\int_{\Omega } |a(x)|^r dx\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}\left(\int_{\Omega } |u(x)|^p dx\right)^{\frac{3}{p}}\left(\int_{\Omega } |v(x)|^q dx\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
Since for any $r>1$ we can find $p>3 , q>1 $ such that  $$\frac{3}{p}+\frac{1}{q} +\frac{1}{r} =1$$ it is enough that $a\in L^r (\Omega )$ for some $r>1.$